# React form field with multiple identical fields

Tags: reactjs, arrays, forms, react-hooks, next.js

[form field image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohYG6.png)

how do I receive identical form field separately so I can add them to the database. like 3 email input fields or so...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question requires more clarification.

If you are using single submit button it can be either of two things, if you are using controlled inputs, as soon as your form is submitted, you can use your state to pass all the data to the backend.

For controlled input you will need to pass onChange handler in each input. Since you are using identical fields I suggest using array of objects and use the index of the array to update the data in the specific index.

If you are using uncontrolled input then you can use form data to retrieve values from the form.

Do remember that you need 'name' in each input for this work.

```html
<form onSubmit={savePassengerSeats}>
      <label>
        Full Name
        <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" />
      </label>
         <label>
        Mobile
        <input type="number" id="mobile" name="mobile" />
      </label>
      <! -- other input  -->
      <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

```js
const savePassengerSeats = (event)=>{
  const formData = new FormData(event.target)
  //use this form data to save data in the db
}
```